# I can't see substring method in java

Tags: java, string, substring

I wanted to create a binary search tree in java. Keys will be Strings and I will compare Strings alphabetically. I wanted to turn my "key"s into char array so I can easily write a method to check the alphabetic order. Unfortunately i couldn't use any of String methods except `equals()`,`getClass()`, `wait()`, `toString()`,`HashCode()`,`Notify()`. I want to use `substring` method and `toCharArray()` method like stringName.substring() or stringName.toCharArray(), but I couldn't reach them. The code is below:

```
public class BST<V,String> {

    public class Node <V,String> {

        private Node right=null;
        private Node left=null;

        private String key;

        private V value=null;

        public Node(V value, String key){
                this.key=key;
                this.value=value;

            }
        }

    Node root=null;
    Node temp=null;

    public void add(V value, String key){
            if(isEmpty()){
                root.value=value;
                root.key=key;
            }
            else{
                temp=root;
                    while(true){
                    if(key > temp.key){
                        if(temp.right==null){
                            Node node= new Node(value,key);
                            temp.right=node;
                        }
                        temp=temp.right;
                        }
                    else if(key < temp.key)
                        if(temp.left==null){
                            Node node= new Node(value,key);
                            temp.left=node;
                        }
                        temp=temp.left;
                    }
            }
        }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(root.value==null){
            return true;
        }
        else 
            return false;

    }


}
```

Comment: i want to react to substring() method like stringName.substring() but it gives me error in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring this:

```
public class BST<V,String>
```

...you have declared two generic parameters on your class; one named `V`, and the other named `String`.

What you *probably* meant to do was omit the generic type of the key, since you know it's going to be `String` anyway:

```
public class BST<V>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where your mistake is is in the declaration of `public class BST<V,String>`.

You have `String` as a generic argument, and that's hiding the actual String class.  As such, what you write as `String` is actually anything.

The solution is to just abandon the generic argument `String`, resulting in `public class BST<V>`.  Things will work then as `String` will no longer be hidden.

Note that eclipse does give a warning about this:

> The type parameter String is hiding the type String